# htaccess Rewrite Error & 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost, hosting

I've been working on my htaccess file to allow rewritten URL paths and everything works fine on my Localhost but when I upload it to the server and type in the url I get a 404 saying:

> The requested URL /****** was not found on this server. Additionally,
>   a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I've tried to ask my hosting account support team but they say they can't help with this type of problem.  My htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^issue=(.*?)&edition=(.*?)&id=(.*?)&title=(.*?)$
RewriteRule ^article.php$ /article/%1/%2/%3/%4 [L,R]
```

And an example url is:

```
http://mywebsite.co.uk/article/1/leeds/1394216062/jupiter-falls-to-tour-with-syron-vanes-and-rdc
```

Why am I getting the 404 & how can I sort this?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Did you read the question? WHY am I getting an error 404 on the live server? Works fine on the localhost

Comment: Are you entering your example url in address bar? Or it get changed after redirection.

Comment: I'm entering that into the address bar

Comment: @user3177012 your edit added the question. So no I didn't read it because it didn't exist when I commented.

Comment: If you're entering it into the address bar, nothing in that rewrite rule will match, so your content must not exist.

Comment: @user3177012 How this going to work> You have no query strings that you have in htaccess condition. Your condition will never met.

Comment: I'm uisng php in the article page to filter out the ID. It all works fine on my localhost but not live - I've tried entering it as a query string and I still get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have written the reverse rule. Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?issue=$1&edition=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will handle: `/article/1/leeds/1394216062/jupiter-falls-to-tour-with-syron-vanes-and-rdc` URLs.

Comment: Just a quick question regarding this, I've just posted to my website and have `<a>` links inside the posts and when I try to visit these links in the page I get `www.website.co.uk/article/1/leeds/1394216062/jupiter-falls-to-tour-with-syron-vanes-and-rdc/http://www.youtube.co..........etc` and the link doesn't work. Is this anything to do with the rewritten URL path code because everything worked fine before?

Comment: Why is `/http://www.youtube.co..` appearing after `www.website.co.uk/article/1/leeds/1394216062/jupiter-falls-to-tour-with-syron-v‌​anes-and-rdc` ?

Comment: That's what I'd like to know. For some reason it's not picking up that http is a different site link - I'm trying to go back to shortening the URL as `www.website.co.uk/article.php?issue=1&edition=leeds&id=1394216062&title=jupiter-falls-to-tour-with-syron-v‌​‌​anes-and-rdc` to `www.website.co.uk/article/1/leeds/1394216062/jupiter-falls-to-tour-with-syron-v‌​‌​anes-and-rdc` - Could you help me with that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. What is the URL showing in your browser? Isn't it `/article/1/leeds/1394216062/jupiter-falls-to-tour-with-syron-vanes-and-rdc`?

Comment: Yes sorry, the url redirection that you gave me works fine but the other errors that I'm getting with the site has made me change how I redirect people so I'm trying to do it the "proper" way!

Comment: What do you mean by "proper way"? I saw your other question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811917/rewriting-an-url-with-htaccess so let's continue discussion there.