# Rewriting an URL with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

After facing many problems with the htaccess rewrite rule as it is at the moment I have decided to change it to something more basic but I cannot get the end page to pick up the ID.

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /article\.php\?issue=(.*)&edition=(.*)&id=(.*)&title=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /article/%2/%3/%4/%5\? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /article.php?issue=$1&edition=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [L]
```

How do I get the article page to pick up the ID number?

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess? You're capturing only 2 groups and using 4 which is incorrect.

Comment: I've edited my original post

Comment: Yes I noticed and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/article\.php\?issue=([^&]*)&edition=([^&]*)&id=([^&]*)&title=([^&\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?issue=$1&edition=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Use of `-MultiViews` is very important here. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: Ah right, thank you again - That works great. I'm going to try it again on a live server so hopefully the new links that I add in will not be a problem now. I still can't understand why the http:// of my links were being added to the end of my URL

Comment: That might be due to some other problem in your HTML

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but it's the same code that I have used for previous posts and they went in fine. I'm noticing that when I add a message with '' in it is slashing them out to become "Leeds alternative rockers \'Bricks Without Straw\' are..." Also, the links that I add are being placed on the end of my web url. This is still happening - Do you have any ideas why or what the problem may be?

Comment: I can't guess problem in your code with limited information. I can only assure that above rules are working fine and I have tested them on my side.

Comment: I've been through the database and removed all back slashes and it's all working fine now. Seems that maybe mysqli_real_escape_string has stopped working for my form $_post functions. I read that my host has updated their server so maybe something has been altered for this to have stopped working - Thanks very much for all your help with the URL Rewrite though, everything there is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /article.php?      issue=$1&edition=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [L]
```

you can use this site

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: For some reason I keep getting the 500 Error when I add anything to the .htaccess file

Comment: I've tried that site and the code it gave me does not shorten the URL when I add it to the address bar

Comment: if you didnt made your php.ini configurations you have to do it first

Comment: The htaccess file works but just not for this example. I want to convert the first link (article.php?var=1&var=2) to the second (article/1/2) as explained above

Comment: Can you set the following settings to find the real problem: in htaccess

    php_flag display_errors on
in php script need add

    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
And you will get error messages

Comment: In my .htaccess I now have: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /article.php?issue=$1&edition=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [L]` which lets me load up the page with NO errors, however the url remains in it's original form as `id=1&title=...` - How do I get it to shorten?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ article.php?issue=$1&edition=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [L]

Comment: You can also check this. http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html

Comment: Thank you but again it doesn't shorten - Am I doing this right? I  type in `http://website.co.uk/article.php?issue=1&edition=leeds&id=1392214680-926677045&title=dearly-noted-presents---lace-and-leather` to the browser address bar & I'm expecting it to automatically shorten to `http://website.co.uk/article/1/leeds/1392214680-926677045/dearly-noted-presents---lace-and-leather` - Is this what should happen?

Comment: you should use this to your code like this. <a href="http://website.co.uk/article.php?issue=1&edition=leeds&id=1392214680-926677045&‌​title=dearly-noted-presents---lace-and-leather" > http://website.co.uk/article.php?issue=1&edition=leeds&id=1392214680-926677045&‌​title=dearly-noted-presents---lace-and-leather </a>

Comment: That's what I'm doing but the url doesn't shorten. I did one thing that did work but then the ID wasn't picked up with GET because it didn't exist in the url - How do sites like stackoverflow use this method & still get the ID number to be recognised?

Comment: ([0-9]+) can you use this for id field not this ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)

Comment: Yes but that still makes no difference - The URL Does Not shorten

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /article\.php\?issue=(.*)&edition=(.*)&id=(.*)&title=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /article/%2/%3/%4/%5\? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^article/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /article.php?issue=$1&edition=$2&id=$3&title=$4 [L]
```

It should change
`http://website.local.co.uk/article.php?issue=1&edition=leeds&id=1392214680-926677045&title=dearly-noted-presents---lace-and-leather`
 to 
`http://website.local.co.uk/article/1/leeds/1392214680-926677045/dearly-noted-presents---lace-and-leather`

EDIT:

```
<?php 
    echo $_GET["issue"];
    echo $_GET["edition"];
    echo $_GET["id"];
    echo $_GET["title"];
?>
```

You can change `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect works correctly.

Comment: Thanks, That works but it's not picking up the ID with php GET - How do I allow this?

Comment: `$id = $_GET["id"];`?

Comment: Yes I have that in the php script but it doesn't capture the id - Maybe because id=111 doesn't now exist in the URL

Comment: I have edited in what I put in the `article.php` file. The issue, edition, id, and title are printed to the screen for me. The id is in the url between `leeds` and `dearly-noted`

Comment: Well why can't I pick it up?

Comment: Is the id the only one that isn't getting displayed for you?

Comment: NO - When I load up article (i.e. I load up the page) There is nothing on there!

Comment: I type in say article.php?id=111 and it shortens to article/111 which I want it to do, but it is not picking up id=111 on the article page

Comment: That is because the first value after `article/` is seen as the issue number, the next one is seen as the edition etc

Comment: In your example you specified that the id would be the third parameter  in the url (issue being the first, edition being the second and id being the third).